# Convert a table HTML String to JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html-table

I'm using [this table to JSON](http://lightswitch05.github.io/table-to-json/) library which parses an HTML Table to JSON from its ID (`#testtable` in this example):

```
var table = $('#testtable').tableToJSON();
alert(JSON.stringify(table));
```

But I want to parse the Table from a String. Like this:

```
var table = $('<table id="example-table"> <thead> <tr> <th>First Name</th> <th>Last Name</th> <th data-override="Score">Points</th></tr> </thead> <tbody> <tr> <td>Jill</td> <td>Smith</td> <td data-override="disqualified">50</td></tr> <tr> <td>Eve</td> <td>Jackson</td> <td>94</td></tr> <tr> <td>John</td> <td>Doe</td> <td>80</td></tr> <tr> <td>Adam</td> <td>Johnson</td> <td>67</td></tr> </tbody> </table>').tableToJSON();
```

How could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin has the option to `ignoreHiddenRows`. Simply set it to false:

```
var table = $('<table>...</table>').tableToJSON({ignoreHiddenRows: false});
```

#### Demo:

```js
var table = $('<table id="example-table"> <thead> <tr> <th>First Name</th> <th>Last Name</th> <th data-override="Score">Points</th></tr> </thead> <tbody> <tr> <td>Jill</td> <td>Smith</td> <td data-override="disqualified">50</td></tr> <tr> <td>Eve</td> <td>Jackson</td> <td>94</td></tr> <tr> <td>John</td> <td>Doe</td> <td>80</td></tr> <tr> <td>Adam</td> <td>Johnson</td> <td>67</td></tr> </tbody> </table>').tableToJSON({ignoreHiddenRows: false});

alert(JSON.stringify(table));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/lightswitch05/table-to-json/master/src/jquery.tabletojson.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the plugin wants the table to be both in the DOM and visible (I tried it in a hidden container).

You can create an offscreen container to append to and then run plugin:

```
<div id="hidden-div" style="position:absolute; top:-999em; left:-999em"></div>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
  var $table = $('<table id="example-table"> <thead> <tr> <th>First Name</th> <th>Last Name</th> <th data-override="Score">Points</th></tr> </thead> <tbody> <tr> <td>Jill</td> <td>Smith</td> <td data-override="disqualified">50</td></tr> <tr> <td>Eve</td> <td>Jackson</td> <td>94</td></tr> <tr> <td>John</td> <td>Doe</td> <td>80</td></tr> <tr> <td>Adam</td> <td>Johnson</td> <td>67</td></tr> </tbody> </table>')
  $('#hidden-div').append($table);
  var table = $table.tableToJSON();
  console.log(table);
});
```

Then remove the offscreen element:

```
$('#hidden-div').remove()
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/AUnL6WJCa90OjkevPux5?p=preview)**</kbd>